# How to create a static library (not executable) in CMake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake, static-libraries

I'm new to cmake and I was wondering how to create a static library. In gcc, it can be done by:

```
ar rsv
```

Well, how do you do it using CMake?

```
add_library(mylib STATIC file1.cpp file2.cpp)
add_executable(myexe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexe mylib)
```

This generates a static library (.a file) but how do you compile it without adding an executable?
if I remove add_executable(myexe main.cpp), it gives me an error. I only want this file:

```
mylib.a
```

and NOT

```
myexe.exe
mylib.a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_library` can be used by itself, without using `add_executable` at all. Simply remove line 2 to get rid of the executable. The error is most likely caused by line 3, which needs `myexe` to function. Line 3 should also be removed, because you are only building the library and not linking it.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I just need to remove:

```
add_executable(myexe main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexe mylib)
```

and this will work.